# Celery Remote task Blocking Request

Tags: python, http, flask, celery, amqp

I've a problem with remote task calling via tornado app with REST call . 
In my case I've tasks that working on another machine  , and another rest api working on another machine .

```
 from flask import Flask 

 celery_obj = //CELERY .

 @app.route("/task1")
 def func():
     celery_obj.send_task(name="tasks.task1", args=[])
```

When I start the application and send the request to the /taksk1 endpoint, flask app cannot reply anything  .

What is the reason of this problem . 
Please help.

Comment: Is `celery_obj = //CELERY .` a typo?

Comment: It just a summarized definition.  I've defined , celery client and rabbitmq connection string

Comment: We need that line expanded so we can see how you're instantiating celery_obj.  Please put `*` instead of any passwords.

Answer (score 1):

`celery_obj` needs to be the celery application that you are sending it to with a minimum of the broker url specified.

e.g.,

```
from celery.app import Celery
celery = Celery(broker='redis://127.0.0.1/1')
celery.send_task('task.name', kwargs={})
```

Comment: I don't see any valid python defining a celery class in your code snippet, so ....??